# Input hexadecimal values into windows command prompt

Tags: cmd, exploit, shellcode

I started to learn exploits and decided to code some simple program to "play" with it.
The code is really simple:
scanf("%s", &var1);
strcpy( buffer, var1);

I coded the program on windows xp and ran it on ollydbg. Found that i could override the SEH, but when i run the program, it opens on a cmd prompt and i cant paste the hexadecimal code (the exploit), only ascii characters. 
For example: i need to past the hex 0x90 but if i past it it'll consider as ascii "0x90". I tried to paste something like \x90, but the same deal, the cmd and the program consider this as ascii characters.

So, how can i be able to input my hexed shellcode into the program on the cmd prompt

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want [`strtoul`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtoul.3.html), which will convert hex characters into binary.

```
   unsigned long int strtoul(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);

   unsigned long long int strtoull(const char *nptr, char **endptr,
                                   int base);
```

Comment: Not exactly, i don't want to modify the program, but find a way to input hex char into the scanf (on windows command prompt )

Comment: @Dan, how did you solve?